# What to do when "Cancelling query" is never-ending

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have a database in another server with 8 SPs and 11 tables.

I wanted to create all of this is in my new Azure SQL Database, so I generated a script with all the DB objects and the handful of sample data. Then I ran the script in the new DB, obviously changing the `USE` to the new name.

After 30 seconds I decided to stop the execution. It's been 20 minutes and it's still "Cancelling execution...". I can't stop the database and I don't have permission to kill tasks.

What can I do?

[image]

Comment: As a side note, Azure SQL Databases don't support `USE`; they are contained databases. You need to explicitly connect to the correct database.